# Proguard for shrinking JAR not correctly picking up dependent classes

Tags: proguard

I am a newbie to using Proguard (which seems immensely useful!). I wish to create a minimal JAR (without any obfuscation whatsover) using a starting point (say a public interface) and was hoping that proguard will pick up the dependent classes transitively. The dependent class however seems to be lacking the private members, its public getter/setters and annotations Only the constructor and toString method are available. Concretely, my SpecialService interface refers to SpecialObject (and maybe many others). I was wondering if it is possible to only mention SpecialService as a keep class and all its dependent (non-library)c lasses (with all of the attributes - no obfuscation or optimization) should be pulled in the output jar.

```
<options>
    <option>-keepattributes</option>
    <option>-keep @javax.ws.rs.Path public class com.kilo.SpecialService { private public protected *;}</option>
</options>
```

I have tried all configurations, but it doesn't seem to work.

SpecialService.java:

```
@GET
@Path("someComplexObjectsWithIntInputs")
List<SpecialObject> getSomeComplexObjectsWithIntInputs(
        @QueryParam("ids") List<Integer> ids);
```

SpecialObject.java

```
public class SpecialObject {
private String name;
private Integer id;
private Date date;
public SpecialObject() {
}
public SpecialObject(String name, Integer id, Date date) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.date = date;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}
public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}
public String getFoo() {
    return "foo";
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "SpecialObject [name=" + name + ", id=" + id + ", date=" + date
            + "]";
}
```

Output SpecialObject.java:

```
/*    */ public class SpecialObject
/*    */ {
/*    */   public String toString()
/*    */   {
/* 56 */     return "SpecialObject [name=" + null + ", id=" + null + ", date=" + null + "]";
/*    */   }
/*    */ }
```

Thanks in advance!

I have added a sample setup @ https://github.com/kilokahn/proguard-tester/blob/master/proguard-tester-parent/proguard-tester-rs-api/pom.xml if someone wishes to play around

Answer (score 2):

Figured out the simple config to do this. Stupid me!

```
<option>-keepclassmembers class * { *;}</option>
```

Updated the setup to reflect this.